# Dart: When you import a file do you import everything that file imports?

Tags: dart, import

Ex.

Files:

- 1.dart
- 2.dart
- 3.dart

2.dart:

```
import 'package:packagename/3.dart';
```

1.dart

```
import 'package:packagename/2.dart';
```

Does 1.dart import 3.dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you import a file you import

- everything public declared in the imported file
- everything public declared in part files of the imported file
- everything explicitly `export`ed from the imported file

If it is not explicitly exported in it won't be imported transitively.

`1.dart` does not import `3.dart` in your example.

If `2.dart` would contain

```
export 'package:packagename/3.dart';
```

then `1.dart` would also import `3.dart`